# How to add custom control for adding a next/previous tracks button inside my player - JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I want to add the **previous/next track button** (btnNext/btnPrev) Inside my grey player on the **left-side of the play button**. I still did not figure out what I have to do in my Js or in my CSS code to make it work.

I have try adding the custom control but Previous track and next track is not listed

```
[
   'play-large', // The large play button in the center
   'restart', // Restart playback
   'rewind', // Rewind by the seek time (default 10 seconds)
   'play', // Play/pause playback
   'fast-forward', // Fast forward by the seek time (default 10 seconds)
   'progress', // The progress bar and scrubber for playback and buffering
   'current-time', // The current time of playback
   'duration', // The full duration of the media
   'mute', // Toggle mute
   'volume', // Volume control
   'captions', // Toggle captions
   'settings', // Settings menu
   'pip', // Picture-in-picture (currently Safari only)
   'airplay', // Airplay (currently Safari only)
   'download', // Show a download button with a link to either the current source or a custom URL you specify in your options
   'fullscreen', // Toggle fullscreen
];
```

[image: Like in classic audio player]

HAVE A LOOK TO MY FIDDLE: ***http://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/1oL6w5jm/23/***

Precious help to improve my code?

Note:
This audio player features playlist support via JSON data and step navigation. The version you're seeing now is a fresh new take on this project... by modernizing the style and offloading all browser detection crap to a wonderful audio player plugin called Plyr (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    'use strict'
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {
        // initialize plyr
        var player = new Plyr('#audio1', {
            controls: [
                'restart',
                'play',
                'progress',
                'current-time',
                'duration',
                'mute',
                'volume',
                'download'
            ]
        });
        // initialize playlist and controls
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [{
                "track": 1,
                "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                "duration": "2:46",
                "file": "JLS_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 2,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "8:30",
                "file": "BS_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 3,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "5:01",
                "file": "BS_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 4,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "8:31",
                "file": "BSFM_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 5,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "BSFM_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 6,
                "name": "All This Is - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "AC_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 7,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 1) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:44",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 8,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 2) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:26",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 9,
                "name": "Magus - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "AC_M"
            }, {
                "track": 10,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address (fucked up) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:25",
                "file": "AC_TSOWAfucked_up"
            }, {
                "track": 11,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "5:53",
                "file": "PNY04-05_M"
            }, {
                "track": 12,
                "name": "On The Waterfront - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "4:40",
                "file": "PNY04-05_OTW"
            }, {
                "track": 13,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "13:15",
                "file": "PNY04-05_T"
            }, {
                "track": 14,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "8:12",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 15,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "7:02",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 16,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:43",
                "file": "PVD_M"
            }, {
                "track": 17,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "10:45",
                "file": "PVD_T"
            }, {
                "track": 18,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:36",
                "file": "PVD_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 19,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 20,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_M"
            }, {
                "track": 21,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "13:07",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_BTPE"
            }, {
                "track": 22,
                "name": "Innocence - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:16",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_I"
            }, {
                "track": 23,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 24,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "4:51",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 25,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "8:43",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 26,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "3:00",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 27,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "6:09",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 28,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 29,
                "name": "Trance - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "12:32",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_T"
            }, {
                "track": 30,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "8:56",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 31,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "4:55",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 32,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "5:45",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 33,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "14:05",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 34,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "13:25",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 35,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:37",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 36,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:36",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_2"
            }],
            buildPlaylist = $.each(tracks, function(key, value) {
                var trackNumber = value.track,
                    trackName = value.name,
                    trackDuration = value.duration;
                if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                    trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                }
                $('#plList').append('<li> \
                    <div class="plItem"> \
                        <span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '.</span> \
                        <span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span> \
                        <span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span> \
                    </div> \
                </li>');
            }),
            trackCount = tracks.length,
            npAction = $('#npAction'),
            npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
            audio = $('#audio1').on('play', function () {
                playing = true;
                npAction.text('Now Playing...');
            }).on('pause', function () {
                playing = false;
                npAction.text('Paused...');
            }).on('ended', function () {
                npAction.text('Paused...');
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
            btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').on('click', function () {
                if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                    index--;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            li = $('#plList li').on('click', function () {
                var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                if (id !== index) {
                    playTrack(id);
                }
            }),
            loadTrack = function (id) {
                $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                index = id;
                audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
                updateDownload(id, audio.src);
            },
            updateDownload = function (id, source) {
                player.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
                    $('a[data-plyr="download"]').attr('href', source);
                });
            },
            playTrack = function (id) {
                loadTrack(id);
                audio.play();
            };
        extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
        loadTrack(index);
    } else {
        // no audio support
        $('.column').addClass('hidden');
        var noSupport = $('#audio1').text();
        $('.container').append('<p class="no-support">' + noSupport + '</p>');
    }
});
```

```
/* Album thumbnail should display here when track is playing
================================================== */
.flex-container {
    width:70vh;
    //pointer-events:none;
  display:block;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:999999999999;
    position:fixed;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    //background:black;
}

.track-thumbnails img {
  //transform: rotate(5deg);
  width: 40vh;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.56); 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);

}

/* Font Family
================================================== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700');


/* Global Styles
================================================== */

html,body {
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
background-color:#0665a2;
color:#fff;
font-size:1rem;
font-family:"Oxygen", HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
letter-spacing:.025rem;
line-height:1.618;
padding:1rem 0;
}

*,::before,::after {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}


/* Setup
================================================== */

.container { position:relative; margin:0 auto; max-width:800px; width:100%; }
.column { width:inherit; }


/* Typography / Links
================================================== */

p { color:#fff; display:block; font-size:.9rem; font-weight:400; margin:0 0 2px; }

a,a:visited { color:#8cc3e6; outline:0; text-decoration:underline; }
a:hover,a:focus { color:#bbdef5; }
p a,p a:visited { line-height:inherit; }


/* Misc.
================================================== */

.add-bottom { margin-bottom:2rem !important; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.center { text-align:center; }
.hidden { display:none; }

.no-support {
margin:2rem auto;
text-align:center;
width:90%;
}


/* Audio Player Styles
================================================== */

audio {
display:none;
}

#audiowrap,
#plwrap {
margin:0 auto;
}

#tracks {
font-size:0;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#nowPlay {
display:block;
font-size:0;
}

#nowPlay span {
display:inline-block;
font-size:1.05rem;
vertical-align:top;
}

#nowPlay span#npAction {
padding:21px;
width:30%;
}

#nowPlay span#npTitle {
padding:21px;
text-align:right;
width:70%;
}

#plList li {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:21px 0;
}

#plList li:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plItem {
position:relative;
}

.plTitle {
left:50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:65px;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
top:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.plNum {
padding-left:21px;
width:25px;
}

.plLength {
padding-left:21px;
position:absolute;
right:21px;
top:0;
}

.plSel,
.plSel:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
cursor:default !important;
}

#tracks a {
border-radius:3px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-size:2.3rem;
height:35px;
line-height:.175;
margin:0 5px 30px;
padding:10px 15px;
text-decoration:none;
transition:background .3s ease;
}

#tracks a:last-child {
margin-left:0;
}

#tracks a:hover,
#tracks a:active {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
}

#tracks a::-moz-focus-inner {
border:0;
padding:0;
}


/* Plyr Overrides
================================================== */

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls {
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
color:#fff;
padding:20px 20px 20px 13px;
width:100%;
}

a.plyr__controls__item.plyr__control:hover,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button:hover,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button.tab-focus:focus,
.plyr__play-large {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr__progress--played,
.plyr__volume--display {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer,
.plyr--audio .plyr__volume--display {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}


/* Media Queries
================================================== */

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #nowPlay span#npAction { display:none; }
    #nowPlay span#npTitle { display:block; text-align:center; width:100%; }
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css">





<div class="container">
    <div class="column add-bottom">
        <div id="mainwrap">
            <div id="nowPlay">
                <span id="npAction">Paused...</span><span id="npTitle"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="audiowrap">
                <div id="audio0">
                    <audio id="audio1" preload controls>Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio! </audio>
                </div>
                <div id="tracks">




<div class="flex-container"><div class="track-thumbnails">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_171d59a550b%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_171d59a550b%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.7109375%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
</div></div>






                    <a id="btnPrev">&vltri;</a><a id="btnNext">&vrtri;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="plwrap">
                <ul id="plList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column add-bottom center">
        <p>Music by <a href="http://www.mythium.net/">Mythium</a></p>
        <p>Download: <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_vbr_mp3.zip">zip</a> / <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_archive.torrent">torrent</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.5.6/plyr.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation on how to add custom controls?
https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/CONTROLS.md

Comment: @TadWohlrapp Yes Tad but I`m not so good in JS, unfortunately. Could you help me to figure out how I could fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/CONTROLS.md#using-custom-html shows you exactly how and where to add html code for custom buttons.
Taking your code and adding custom buttons from the docs example: http://jsfiddle.net/zvj0taku/

Comment: Thanks, @TadWohlrapp, but is only take the audio-track 10 seconds after (same in the fiddle you have sent me), I would need to go to the next track. Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, it was only an example how to place buttons inside the player ui, which is what your question asks...
For functionality, check the playlist discussion here: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/3

Comment: @TadWohlrapp not very helpful unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213018/discussion-between-cat-and-tad-wohlrapp).